# Handbrake CLI command not working

Tags: handbrake

I am trying to get the HB CLI to run this command removing the framerate (as the default ATV2 is 30fps and in the UK that looks rubbish, I want it to use the source fps

./HandBrakeCLI -i DVD -o ~/Movies/movie.mp4 -e x264  -q 20.0 -a 1,1 -E faac,copy:ac3 -B 160,160 -6 dpl2,none -R Auto,Auto -D 0.0,0.0 --audio-copy-mask aac,ac3,dtshd,dts,mp3 --audio-fallback ffac3 -f mp4 -4 -X 1280 -Y 720 --loose-anamorphic --modulus 2 -m --x264-preset medium --h264-profile high --h264-level 3.1

This is the default I changed the **Bold** well removed it

./HandBrakeCLI -i DVD -o ~/Movies/movie.mp4 -e x264  -q 20.0 **-r 30 --pfr**  -a 1,1 -E faac,copy:ac3 -B 160,160 -6 dpl2,none -R Auto,Auto -D 0.0,0.0 --audio-copy-mask aac,ac3,dtshd,dts,mp3 --audio-fallback ffac3 -f mp4 -4 -X 1280 -Y 720 --loose-anamorphic --modulus 2 -m --x264-preset medium --h264-profile high --h264-level 3.1

but it doesn't seem to work, I don't know if I have missed something, any help would be useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

figured it out by the looks of it

{{{
   ./HandBrakeCLI -i DVD -o ~/Movies/movie.mp4 -e x264  -q 20.0 -a 1,1 -E faac,copy:ac3 -B 160,160 -6 dpl2,none -R Auto,Auto -D 0.0,0.0 --audio-copy-mask aac,ac3,dtshd,dts,mp3 --audio-fallback ffac3 -f mp4 -4  -4 -X 1280 -Y 720 --decomb --loose-anamorphic --modulus 2 -m --x264-preset medium --h264-profile high --h264-level 4.1
}}}

I was missing the {{{ }}} which there was nothing about in the manual unless I missed it